# How to display csv data in html as URL using flask?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

With the flask app, I managed to display the my.csv file in an HTML table. Now I'm trying to add URL to each userId that is displayed in HTML table (see Output), for example:
https://myURL.com/1
https://myURL.com/2 etc...

What would be the best way to achieve this assuming that once I click on the userId URL in userID column it will bring me to an HTML page with more details specific for that ID.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/example')
def dataframe():
    df = pd.read_csv("my.csv")
    return render_template("example.html",  data=df.head(5).to_html())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**example.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSV Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My stats</h1> 

{{data | safe}}

</body>
</html>
```

**output: http://127.0.0.1:5000/example**

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can render HTML from Pandas and then render that HTML in Flask, the problem is that approach prevents additional edits to the HTML. To get started with the task, I created some synthetic data in Pandas

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([{"userID": 4, "customers": 23},
                       {"userID": 3, "customers": 33},
                       {"userID": 1, "customers": 42},
                       {"userID": 5, "customers": 13},])
print(df.to_html())
```

To include URLs, a naive method would be to try to embed the links as strings in the Pandas dataframe prior to generating the HTML. The problem is that Pandas converts strings:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([{"userID": "<a href='helo'>4</a>", "customers": 23},
                       {"userID": 3, "customers": 33},
                       {"userID": 1, "customers": 42},
                       {"userID": 5, "customers": 13},])
print(df.to_html())
```

produces a cell that contains the string `&lt;a href='helo'&gt;4&lt;/a&gt;`

To keep the hyperlink as HTML, tell Pandas to not escape special characters.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([{"userID": "<a href='helo'>4</a>", "customers": 23},
                       {"userID": 3, "customers": 33},
                       {"userID": 1, "customers": 42},
                       {"userID": 5, "customers": 13},])
print(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

Next task is to inject links into the dataframe:

```
list_of_rows = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    new_row = {'customers': dict(row)['customers']} # keep the old data
    uid = str(dict(row)['userID'])
    new_row['userID'] = "<a href='http://url.com/"+uid+"'>"+uid+"</a>"
    list_of_rows.append(new_row)
df_with_links = pandas.DataFrame(list_of_rows)
```

Incorporating those techniques into your code,

```
@app.route('/example')
def dataframe():
    df = pd.read_csv("my.csv")
    list_of_rows = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        new_row = {'customers': dict(row)['customers']} # keep the old data
        uid = str(dict(row)['userID'])
        new_row['userID'] = "<a href='http://url.com/"+uid+"'>"+uid+"</a>"
        list_of_rows.append(new_row)
    df_with_links = pandas.DataFrame(list_of_rows)

    return render_template("example.html",  data=df_with_links.to_html(escape=False))
```